# Actions on Google Simulator not working

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I follow the actions on Google instruction, just have one action which is the default welcome intent.
I always get this error when I type "talk to XXX ".

Also, I tried the google smart home action example, I could see my devices on mobile assist APP - home control, but I had some error when I test on the simulator like "turn on my lights".

Anyone know what could cause this issue? Thanks!

```json
{
 "response": "We're sorry, but something went wrong. Please try again.",
 "expectUserResponse": false,
 "conversationToken": "",
 "audioResponse": "",
 "visualResponse": {
  "visualElementsList": [
  {
    "displayText": {
      "content": "Sorry, this action is not available in simulation"
    }
  }
],
"suggestionsList": [],
"agentLogoUrl": ""
},
"clientError": 4,
"is3pResponse": false
}
```

**UPDATE**

Hi, this issue is fixed. It is because APP activity control is turned off by the company account Administrator, even though I enabled web & App activity on my account.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You'll get a better response if you also include some code in your question that exhibits the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

When you are simulating a conversational action, are you making sure that the project is currently in a 'test draft' state? You may want to disable and re-enable testing by clicking on the testing button in the top right corner of the console. 
[image: Actions on Google console screenshot]

If you are testing a smart home action, you can't make calls such as "talk to X" as there is no conversational entrypoint for a smart home action. However, after you do account linking commands like "turn on lights" should correctly send the command to your endpoint only for the currently tested action.

Comment: Nick - did you intend to leak your email in your image?  Might want to redact it

Comment: It's not the first time I've posted my work email on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Outstanding transparency.  Carry on.  Thank you

Comment: Hi Nick, it is in a "test draft" state. Firstly I tried the smart home action, after account linking, I tried "turn on lights", it said "Sure. Let me get some more information so I can help you with that." but nothing happened, no request to the server.  And then I created another custom project using dialogflow to test. Actually it always show the error until I type "turn on something", it shows "sure, ..." which is the same to smart home project. When I tested that, I disable the smart home and make sure the custom action is enable, but still the same issue.

Comment: Does the smart home action work on a phone? Can you toggle testing for your actions? It may be that "turn on something" in your Dialogflow project is inadvertently calling your smart home action because testing that has not been disabled.

Comment: No, it is not working on the phone as well, the assistant also said "Sure, ...", and then stops. If I say "turn on smart light" (smart light is the light name), it shows error, only "turn on lights" it will say "sure ..." . How can I disable the action completely? I click the disable button, it shows "No tests currently active" but when I move my mouse to the icon you show above, it still shows enabled, and I cannot click it again.